# How to change Django's default Postgres database search directory

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am creating a Django web application and I am using Postgres for my database.

Under my project, I have a web application named 'home', and I created a table named 'myTable' in Postgres.

Whenever I try to save something in the table, Django automatically looks for the table called 'home_myTable' instead of 'myTable'. For example, if I do

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "home_myTable" does not exist
```

I have been working around this by manually giving Postgres commands using Psycopg2, but this is really annoying.

Is there a way to stop Django from automatically start looking for 'home_myTable' and instead make it search the table that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`db_table`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#db-table) Meta option for you model.

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mytable'
```

Unless you are dealing with a legacy database, I recommend that you define your models, create migrations, then let Django create the tables, instead of creating the tables manually as you are doing.

Comment: I added `db_table = 'myTable'`, but I still get the same error. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: You might have to delete your migration and recreate it after setting `db_table`. If you are still get errors after that, you'll need to give more details e.g the migration that is failing and the full traceback.